# Run code on specific files in a directory separately (by the name of file)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, import, filenames, nested-loops

I have N files in the same folder with different index numbers like

```
Fe_1Sec_1_.txt
Fe_1Sec_2_.txt
Fe_1Sec_3_.txt

Fe_2Sec_1_.txt
Fe_2Sec_2_.txt
Fe_2Sec_3_.txt
.
.
.
and so on
```

Ex: If I need to run my code with only the files with time = 1 Sec, I can make it manually as follow:

```
path = "input/*_1Sec_*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path)
print(files)
```

which gave me:

```
Out[103]: ['input\\Fe_1Sec_1_.txt', 'input\\Fe_1Sec_2_.txt', 'input\\Fe_1Sec_3_.txt']
```

In case of I need to run my code for all files separately (depending on the measurement time in seconds, i.e. the name of file)
I tried this code to get the path for each time of measurement:

```
time = 0
while time < 4:
   time += 1
   t = str(time)
   path = ('"input/*_'+t+'Sec_*.txt"')
```

which gives me:

```
"input/*_1Sec_*.txt"
"input/*_2Sec_*.txt"
"input/*_3Sec_*.txt"
"input/*_4Sec_*.txt"
```

After that I tried to use this path as follow:

```
files = glob.glob(path)
print(files)
```

But it doesn't import the wanted files and give me :

```
 "input/*_1Sec_*.txt"
 []
 "input/*_2Sec_*.txt"
 []
 "input/*_3Sec_*.txt"
 []
 "input/*_4Sec_*.txt"
 []
```

Any suggestions, please??

Comment: are you accessing your `path` string inside the while loop? If yes, can you show the updated code and error msg if any?

Comment: @mad_
This is the msg

 "input/*_1Sec_*.txt"
[]
"input/*_2Sec_*.txt"
[]
"input/*_3Sec_*.txt"
[]
"input/*_4Sec_*.txt"
[]

Comment: @mad_ you can see the msg in my edit of question

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to simply do

```
for time in range(1, 5):  # 1,2,3,4
    glob_path = 'input/*_{}Sec_*.txt'.format(time)
    for file_path in glob.glob(glob_path):
         do_something(file_path, measurement)  # or whatever
```

Comment: I wonder what is the difference in this piece of code and what OP has posted except string formatting and for->while loop.